Как вытащить значение из { } скобок которое приходит в строке с помощью JS
Строка выглядит так "{1281} - INTERSTELLAR 410", нужно разделить строку с помощью JS и получить цифровое значение отдельно без скобок. цифр может быть в скобках от трех до 5 по количеству. и получить на выходе вот что то подобное
"tovarId": "{{ 1281 }}"


"{1281} - INTERSTELLAR 410".replace(/^\{(\d{3,5})\}.+$/, '{{ $1 }}')


получить цифровое значение отдельно без скобок

Такое можно сделать вот таким образом...


const s = "{1281} - INTERSTELLAR 410"
const r = /(?<={)\d+(?=})/
const v = s.match(r)[0]
console.log(v)
console.log(`"tovarId": "{{ ${v} }}"`)




супер попробую. Я через split пробовал . но не корректно

а как теперь это все преобразовать в json

@ПетрРучкин, что "все"? Я вывожу одно число и одну строку. Что переводить в json-строку?

записать это ввиде JSON и именно с помощью JS чтоб имела такой вид "body":
{
"id": "1281",
"title": "12726442" }

@ПетрРучкин, твой "пример" не JSON-строка... И про title информации не было.
